# Make program first read from pipe, then from keyboard

Tags: command-line, pipe, cat, stdin

Consider the interactive program `interactive`. I have to run this program fairly frequently, and each time I run it the first few commands are the same. Obviously, having to type those commands over and over again is a pain. I have collected those command (separated by newlines) in the file `cmd`. Now I can do `cat cmd | interactive` to run the commands. The problem is that once `cmd` has been fully read, `interactive` recieves EOF and exits.

What I wish to do is first have `interactive` read from the pipe (obviously `interactive < cmd` is also acceptable) and when EOF is received, start reading from the keyboard instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just ask `cat` to concatenate that file with the stdin:

```
cat cmd - | interactive
```

Comment: The above solution is probably optimal. If you're using a gui desktop, then also take a look at AutoKey.  It will let you build macros that can do almost anything you can do from a keyboard.  It gets a little tricky if you have to wait for things to happen, or have to get data from the screen, but if you know python (the language its macros are coded in), the sky is the limit.