# Resume input from user after file is read

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a program that reads user input—moves, it's a boardgame—from the user. Like so:

```
$ game
enter your move: 
# etcetera
```

The first *N* moves I need to repeat each time, so I put them in a text file, one line each. That works:

```
$ game < moves.txt
```

This works, but after these *N* moves, how do I return to input from the command line?

I realize this is probably a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I found it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561055/switch-from-file-contents-to-stdin-in-piped-command-linux-shell:

    (cat moves; cat) | game

Comment: Wasn't necessary to go to SO for that. [Make program first read from pipe, then from keyboard](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55808/make-program-first-read-from-pipe-then-from-keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer on stackoverflow in the mean time, after some more intense Googling:

At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561055/switch-from-file-contents-to-stdin-in-piped-command-linux-shell:

```
(cat moves; cat) | game
```

And a very useful comment by [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109549/zack):

"For those who are interested, you can build onto the file containing commands as you go by using: `(cat your_file_with_commands; tee -a your_file_with_commands) | sh your_script` which will append each command to the file in addition to passing it to the script via the pipe."